# Tkinter syntax error at the "text="some random text"

Tags: python, tkinter, syntax

I am new to programming, and started with python and Tkinter.
I followed this tutorial video online and while trying to understand it, i wrote the code exactly as the guy from the tutorial did. Yet, i get a syntax error and can't run it. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8vXU.png)

I'm sorry, it's my first post here.Ok, so, here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

#key down function
def click():
    entered_text=textentry.get() #this will collect the text from the text entry box
    output.delete(0,0, END)
    try:
        definition = my_compdictionary[entered_text]
    except:
        definition = "Sorry there is no word like that , try again"
        output.insert(END, definition)
#MAIN
window = Tk()
window.title("My computer Science Glosarry")
#MY PHOTO
photo1 = PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/zahar/Desktop/photo2.gif")
Label (window, image=photo1, bg="black") .grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E)
# create label
Label = (window, text="Enter a word you would like a definition for:", bg="black", fg="white", font="none 12 bold") .grid(row1, column=0, sticky=W)
```

Comment: post the smallest version of your code which still reproduces the error in text form for us to copy please.

Comment: `Label = (window, text ...)` isnt correct syntax

Comment: Please don't post links to pictures of code. Take the time to copy, paste, and properly format it directly in the question. Pictures aren't searchable, and we can't copy and paste the code to try to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @BryanOakley in this case we get privat information too. :|

Comment: @Atlas435 it is the OP's burden to provide a [mre] and ensure that personal info is removed.  [Ask] specifically asks the code is posted in question in text format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed something :)

```
Label1 = tk.Label(window..)
#####^use Label1 instead of Label, cause you cold overwrite the tk class
```

#

```
from tkinter import *

#key down function
def click():
    entered_text=textentry.get() #this will collect the text from the text entry box
    output.delete(0,0, END)
    try:
        definition = my_compdictionary[entered_text]
    except:
        definition = "Sorry there is no word like that , try again"
        output.insert(END, definition)
#MAIN
window = Tk()
window.title("My computer Science Glosarry")
#MY PHOTO
photo1 = PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/zahar/Desktop/photo2.gif")
Label(window, image=photo1, bg="black").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E)
# create label
Label(window, text="Enter a word you would like a definition for:", bg="black", fg="white", font="none 12 bold").grid(row1, column=0, sticky=W)
######^ here is the syntax error
###### either you do Label(window...)
###### or you sign a variable to the label like Label1 = Label(window...)
```

Comment: I doubt the purpose is to reassign the name `Label`.

Comment: Either he need to do .configure or he tried to create two. Not sure what he is trying to do

Comment: Avoid using `Label` as variable because it will override the class `Label`.

Comment: My point is the `=` sign is most likely what's superfluous, i.e. `Label = (window, ...)` should be `Label(window, ...)`.

Comment: @r.ook its another possible solution.